# Server.Execute - render .ASP from MVC controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I need to render an ASP page to a string from an MVC controller action. I can use `Server.Execute()` to render a .aspx page, but not a .asp page.

Here's what I'm using:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Server.Execute("/default.asp");
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

which returns

```
`No http handler was found for request type 'GET'`
```

Any suggestions? I can do something similar with with a web request, but I'd rather avoid the overhead of a loopback request.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?  If 7 are you using an integrated pipeline?

Comment: Yes, IIS 7. My production servers are running IIS6 on Win2k3.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, when running under an ASP.NET 3.5 or 4.0 context and using ASP.NET, Server.Execute isn't going to execute a .ASP page because there's no ASP.NET httpHandler configured for legacy .ASP pages.

What I would do is use a WebRequest to execute the .ASP page and store the results, then dump the string output of the response to a string and then dump that string when the controller method is executed. This way, you can even execute a .ASP page on a different server (Server.Execute is NOT farm-friendly!)

Comment: That's what I meant by "loopback request".  It works, but obviously incurs some additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.TransferRequest()` instead of `.Execute()` and it should work. And if it doesn't work in the controller, put it in your view instead, like this:

`@{Server.TransferRequest("/default.asp");}`